# tabs in Windows console

Tags: windows, console, ascii, console-application

My command-line apps often output brief reports to the console. These reports contains TAB characters. If I later copy the output from the console to a text file, I find that the Windows console converted TAB into spaces.

Is there a setting (or an alternative console I can use in Windows) which actually keeps the TAB character in the console window (so I can copy it), but still displays it as if it corresponds to a certain number of spaces?

Comment: Have you considered redirecting stdout to file?  e.g. "myconsoleapp.exe > output.txt"

Comment: Yes, I now redirect to text file precisely for this reason. But it would be more convenient for me to run the application without redirection, and only after seeing the output, decide whether it's worth saving to a text file or Excel, etc.

Comment: I don't believe there is a solution to this. I feel like this isn't limited to Windows -- that you get this effect whenever you select text in any console. A character in a console has a fixed width, so a tab _has_ to be converted to spaces (or at least this is the case because _historically_ a character had a fixed width).